# How do Setup Tableau extract refresh

Tags: tableau-api

How to the setup or configure my extract filters in tableau to always load the current data when admin refreshes the extract

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to be shown the latest data upon every refresh on the dashboard, you will need to use MAX in your worksheets. For example: When the user opens the dashboard, the user is prompted automatically with week 05, next week when you refresh the data extract on server, the user is prompted with week 06. In that scenario, you dont need to change filter or parameter, it is automatic.

There are drawbacks to the use of Max everytime. In some of your worksheets you might not have Week 05 data because of other filters. It returns you Max week to be 03 because you have data for that week. Should be careful and test more when using LODs